# What is the highest spell save DC an AL v.7 legal character can have?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, dnd-adventurers-league, difficulty-class

Out of curiosity, I’ve been calculating what is the highest spell save DC that a character can have, assuming perfect conditions.

My calculations have so far yielded the following result:

- Base of 8
- Proficiency bonus of +7 (level 17+ character attuned to an Ioun Stone of Mastery)
- A charisma of 24 (to my knowledge, there is no way pf having a higher charisma than that, and the only way I know to get a 24 of charisma is thanks to a specific event in a specific hardcover adventure), giving a +7 bonus
- Attunement to a Rod of the pact keeper +3 (assuming that the character is a warlock)
- Attunement to some Robes of the Archmagi, giving another +2 bonus

Total: 27

Am I missing something? Perhaps there is yet another magical item that can increase a character’s spell save DC (assuming that the item in question requires no attunement, or that the character somehow found a way to gain a fourth attunement slot)? Or perhaps a spell, feature, feat, ability, etc.? Or perhaps there is indeed a way to get a 30 of charisma?

The calculation assumes that the character is to be played in Adventurers League v.7 organized play (so no homebrew).

Comment: If you don't want a boring "Infinity" answer consider reading some other "highest X" questions and restricting some of the infinite stat generation methods.

Answer (score 9):

## The highest possible permanent Spell Save DC is 28

### The Character

Chad is a Level 17+ character with at least one level in warlock and these magic items:

- Robe of the Archmagi
- Rod of the Pact Keeper (only applies to your warlock spells)
- Ioun Stone of Mastery
- Tome of Leadership and Influence

### The Calculation

+8 | Base Score
+6 | Level 17+ Proficiency
+1 | Ioun Stone of Mastery (Proficiency increase)
+2 | Robe of the Archmagi
+7 | 24 Charisma (acquired in specific Adventure Module, see below if okay with spoilers)
+1 | +2 Charisma (Tome of Leadership and Influence<sup>1</sup>)
+3 | Rod of the Pact Keeper

### This involves...

> [the Maze Engine from Out of the Abyss (188) which says:]
>  On each of the engines turns, roll a d100 and consult the Maze Engine Effects table to determine what the engine does.
>  [...]
>  36-49 | Loud whispers emanate from the hollow interior of  the engine. Each character in direct contact with the engine can increase one ability score of his or her choice by 2, to a maximum of 24

---

### Rulings

<sup>1</sup> You can only use one Tome/Manual of any one kind on a character in Adventurer's League ([DDAL FAQ v7.1](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) p. 8)

Comment: So DC 28 for *only* the spells gained from Warlock but DC 25 for the rest assuming multi-classing to another caster.

Comment: @Slagmoth Or you can go full Warlock, nothing prevents that. That is just the minimum